# mongodb regex searching issue in meteor

Tags: regex, mongodb, meteor

my code is

```
var search_element=Session.get("search_string");
var adc="/"+search_element+"*/";
console.log(adc);
return Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:adc}});
```

Why it is not working

if i give

`Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:/Best*/}});`

in conslow it's working and if i substitute the regex with the value(search_element) it is not working. I think it is replacing like this

`Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:"/Best*/"}});(with quotes "/Best*/")`

Is that the main problem? or Is there any silly mistake i did??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two types of syntax:

```
Polls_Coll.find({question:/Best*/});
```

and

```
Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:"Best*"}});
```

You've used elements in each so thats probably why its not working. There's a bit more details about this at the mongodb docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Both forms work fine in Meteor, so you shouldn't have a problem with them.

Comment: If u clearly observe my question i tried `Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:"\Best*\"}});` not this `Polls_Coll.find({question:{$regex:"Best*"}});` any way thx for the reply and it's working

Comment: @sasikanth As was commented on the original question response, if you can do it then try to look from the *beginning* of the string using the caret, like this "^Best*". If you do not, your queries will result in collection scans in order to find a match. For large data where you need to match **anywhere** look into tokenizing the content, otherwise you will run into performance issues.

Comment: thx for the suggestion and another question is what if i want to search for a string in all fields of a document.Do u have any idea,how is the query like

Comment: @sasikanth you could do a full text search: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/. You would have to use a few packages to expose a way to do the query too, though (also server side only)

Answer (score 8):

I use this syntax and it's work for me:

```
Polls_Coll.find({ name: {$regex: "adc", $options: '-i'} });
```

It similar with:

```
SELECT * FROM Polls_Coll WHERE name LIKE '%adc%'
```

I also use https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var with implementation like code below:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('customersSearch', function(searchValue){
        if (searchValue) {
            return Customers.find({ name: {$regex: searchValue, $options: '-i'} });
        }
   });
}

var searchQuery = new ReactiveVar();

Template.NewRO.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('vehicles');
        self.subscribe('customersSearch', searchQuery.get());
    });
});
```